# Can't working out incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'

Tags: sql-server, syntax-error

I've hit a wall with the SQL query I'm working on currently. I'm still learning SQL so apologies if this is an easy fix. I'm getting a syntax error on my second LEFT JOIN and for the life of me I can't figure out why.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ci.CatalogItemID AS EID
FROM 
    LodgingCatalogMaster.[dbo].[CatalogItem] ci
LEFT JOIN 
    LodgingCatalogMaster.[dbo].[CatalogItemAttribute] cia ON ci.catalogitemid = cia.catalogitemid
WHERE 
    ci.[TableTypeID] = 1 
    AND ci.catalogitemid NOT IN (SELECT cia.CatalogItemID
                                 FROM LodgingCatalogMaster.[dbo].[CatalogItemAttribute] cia
                                 WHERE cia.attributeID IN (2001, 361, 1073742653))
    AND ci.TableTypeID = 1
    AND ci.CatalogItemStatusTypeID = 1
LEFT JOIN 
   LodgingCatalogMaster.[dbo].[SKUGroupBusinessModel] skugbm ON ci.catalogitemid = skugbm.SkuGroupCatalogItemID
WHERE 
    skugbm.MerchantContract = 1 OR skugbm.DirectAgencyContract = 1;
```

Comment: Because you can't add joins after a where clause.

Comment: You have a WHERE clause in the middle of you joins.  Is that `WHERE` clause supposed to indicate it's part of a sub query being joined to `LodgingCatalogMaster`?  It's hard to tell without the entire qurey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `LEFT JOIN` above your WHERE clause as shown below. The only thing that you should see after a `WHERE` clause is a `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ci.CatalogItemID AS EID
FROM LodgingCatalogMaster.[dbo].[CatalogItem] ci
LEFT JOIN LodgingCatalogMaster.[dbo].[CatalogItemAttribute] cia
        ON ci.catalogitemid = cia.catalogitemid
LEFT JOIN LodgingCatalogMaster.[dbo].[SKUGroupBusinessModel] skugbm
        ON ci.catalogitemid = skugbm.SkuGroupCatalogItemID
WHERE ci.[TableTypeID] = 1 
AND ci.catalogitemid NOT IN (
               SELECT cia.CatalogItemID
               FROM LodgingCatalogMaster.[dbo].[CatalogItemAttribute] cia
               WHERE cia.attributeID in (2001, 361, 1073742653)
               )
    AND ci.TableTypeID = 1
    AND ci.CatalogItemStatusTypeID = 1
    AND (skugbm.MerchantContract = 1 OR skugbm.DirectAgencyContract = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change both of your `WHERE` statements to `AND`.  Since you have left joins the `WHERE` clause could effectively change them to INNER JOINS.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ci.CatalogItemID AS EID FROM LodgingCatalogMaster.[dbo].[CatalogItem] ci

LEFT JOIN LodgingCatalogMaster.[dbo].[CatalogItemAttribute] cia
        ON ci.catalogitemid = cia.catalogitemid AND ci.[TableTypeID] = 1  AND ci.catalogitemid NOT IN (
               SELECT cia.CatalogItemID
               FROM LodgingCatalogMaster.[dbo].[CatalogItemAttribute] cia
               WHERE cia.attributeID in (2001, 361, 1073742653)
               )
    AND ci.TableTypeID = 1
    AND ci.CatalogItemStatusTypeID = 1

LEFT JOIN LodgingCatalogMaster.[dbo].[SKUGroupBusinessModel] skugbm ON ci.catalogitemid = skugbm.SkuGroupCatalogItemID AND skugbm.MerchantContract = 1 OR skugbm.DirectAgencyContract = 1;
```